# Running exec in a script

Tags: php

I have this:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
  exec("./check_sample.sh");
}
?

<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<button type="button" onclick="?run=true">Click Me!</button>
```

The shell script check_sample.sh has some o/p which it prints using printf/echo 
When I click 'Click Me' I don't see those o/p. Also anypointer on how to make it
take a text input and pass it as $1 arg. to script will also help

Comment: Is there any way you can do this without using a shell script/passing parameters to it? Using shell commands without properly escaping input can lead to serious security vulnarabilties.

Answer (score 1):

exec will only give you the last line ... your probably want to use passthru

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
  passthru("./check_sample.sh");
}
?
```

For passing parameters you can just form the add it to the command like this. (escapeshellarg will handle the escaping and quoting of the value for you)

```
  passthru("./check_sample.sh ".escapeshellarg($_POST["fieldname"]));
```

If you need the output as a string your options are to use [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or surround the passthru in an output buffering block: ie:

```
 ob_start(); 
 /* passthru call */ 
 $data = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) doesn't output anything. You could use [`passthru()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).

Be **VERY** careful about passing user input to an external program. If you do make sure you escape it using [`escapeshellarg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Kind of like this:

```
passthru('./check_sample.sh '.escapeshellarg($your_user_input));
```

Answer (score 0):

[exec()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.exec.php) only catches the last line and it seems you'd better use a variable to catch it. see the manual. Other choices is [system()](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.system.php), [shell_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.shell-exec.php), [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.passthru.php), you can find which one is suitable via the PHP manual.

Comment: Actually its not helping. I have it written like this:<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
ob_start();

passthru("./check_sample.sh ".escapeshellarg($_POST["iCSCui21515"]));
$data = ob_get_clean();
}
?>


<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<button type="button" onclick="?run=true">Click Me!</button>
Still nothing comes on screen when i exec that script